# Angular 8 Auxiliary Routes define second router outlet into Child Component

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a problem with setting up the second router-outlet inside my angular app. Below is a graph that presents what I want to achieve:
[image]

The problem is even if I declared in app-routing below path:
`{path:'componentH', component: ComponentH, outlet:'second'}`
I receive an error telling me that the app cannot find the matching path.

Can someone prepare a step-by-step instruction on how to configure that? I found many examples where the second router-outlet was declared in the same place as the primary router-outlet, but I didn't find any example of how to do it for child components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use only one `<router-outlet>` in a same level, you dont need to use named `<router-outlet>`, just use child routes. I provide an example for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9bxfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Frouter-module.ts

Comment: Ok it works for me. Just to confirm - I should use `name` for `router-outlet` only if I want to use it around same component as primary `router-outlet`

Comment: @Sepcio yes, if you want more <router-outlet> in a same template, then you need named <router-outlet> because the router doesnt knows which component need to be loaded into which <router-outlet>.